# Add round icon for Pixel devices

Tags: feature-request, android-app

Android 7.1 added support for [round icons](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.1.html#circular-icons), which are used on the new Pixel devices. It would be nice to see the Stack Exchange app include a round icon so that it aligns with the included apps, which all use a circular icon. The circle has a diameter of `172px` on a `192px` artboard as per the [material design guidelines for product icons](https://material.google.com/style/icons.html#icons-product-icons).

It should only require two changes:

- Compiling with API 25
- Adding a new round icon and specifying it in your manifest with `android:roundIcon`

Many apps embed their regular icon in a white circle, but I would find it more unique if the app icon used the pure white Stack Exchange icon on a colored circular background (closer in style to the Phone app).

Comment: I prefer they spend their time fixing bugs before working on fancy and pointless design. That said, that's not a bad idea.

Comment: TBH, Android Studio's built in Image Asset studio would make the app icon in a white circle  approach only take a few minutes for someone with a high quality version of the current app icon.

Comment: Well, considering they spent 0 minutes fixing bugs in the last couple of years, I wouldn't build my hopes too high.